# Why doesn't text appear in my Entry widget

Tags: python, tkinter

G'day All,

I have a little app that os.walks gathering some data.  While it is working I thought it might be nice to put an Entry widget with the text "Processing" in it and change that to "Completed" when the walking was done.

The issue is the "Processing" never appears.  The processing takes many seconds so it's not like it's over too soon to be seen.

```
def do_search():

txtProgress.delete(0,END)
txtProgress.insert(0, "Processing Data")

print 'do_search called'

arrayOfDirectories = [] # Store the categories here
global path
print  'The value for path = ' + path # Delete this in final
searchpath = path
print  'The value for searchpath = ' + searchpath # Delete this in final

for (searchpath, directories, files) in os.walk(searchpath):
    for directory in directories:
        arrayOfDirectories.append(directory) # Create an array or dirs to use for the categories

id = 1
finalJSON = '['

for eachDirectory in arrayOfDirectories:
    readpath = os.path.join(path, eachDirectory, 'URLS') # Grab each list of URLs
    print('readpath = ' + readpath)

    if os.path.exists(readpath):
        file = open(readpath) # Open the list of URLs
        for lines in file: # Step through each URL in turn

            ruleString = '{"id":' + str(id) + ',"enabled":true, "category":"' + eachDirectory + '","description":"' + lines + '","flagged":true,"string":"' + lines + '","name":"","javaClass":"com.untangle.uvm.node.GenericRule","blocked":true}'
            #print(ruleString)
            finalJSON = finalJSON + ruleString # Create a rule and add it to the final string
            id = id + 1 # Increment the id after each rule
        file.close() # Close the file when all have been read
```

It's not a train smash if it doesn't work but I am at a loss to understand why text is not appearing.

As always, all advice gratefully accepted.

Comment: please fix your indentation and use `import json` instead of your manual json, also globals shouldn't be touched, I've never used one in several years of coding in python.

Comment: Not sure what's wrong with the indentation.  Didn't know there was a json module - thanks for that.  I don't code for a living so whatever gets the job done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, you never give your program a chance to display it. Redrawing the screen only happens as the result of a repaint event, so unless the event loop has a chance to service that event nothing will be displayed. This isn't unique to Tkinter -- all GUI toolkits work this way.

The simple solution is to call `txtProgress.update_idletasks()` whenever you want the screen to be updated. This will allow events that refresh the screen to run. This is not the best solution, but it might solve your immediate problem.

The best solution is to refactor your program to either do the long-running work in a separate thread or process, or break the work down to chunks that can be done one at a time with each iteration of the event loop.

Comment: Thanks for that.  Always something to learn.  I have no need or desire to teach myself threading so I think I might let the progress feature die a quiet death.  I'll try your simple solution just to learn something though.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Just to put the final touches on this project.  I applied both of Bryan's suggestions and used the .update_idletasks() method as well as employing threading.  The final code works as desired and looks like this:

```
from Tkinter import *
import os
import threading
from tkFileDialog import askdirectory

#####################################
# Put the grunt stuff up here       #
#####################################
def loadpath():

    print 'loadpath called'
    global path
    path = askdirectory()
    txtPath.delete(0, END)
    txtPath.insert(0, path)

def update_the_status():
    txtProgress.delete(0,END)
    txtProgress.insert(0, "Processing Data")
    txtProgress.update_idletasks()

def do_the_search():
    print 'do_search called'

    arrayOfDirectories = [] # Store the categories here
    global path
    print  'The value for path = ' + path # Delete this in final
    searchpath = path
    print  'The value for searchpath = ' + searchpath # Delete this in final

    for (searchpath, directories, files) in os.walk(searchpath):
        for directory in directories:
           arrayOfDirectories.append(directory) # Create an array or dirs to use for the categories

    id = 1
    finalJSON = '['
    for eachDirectory in arrayOfDirectories:
        readpath = os.path.join(path, eachDirectory, 'URLS') # Grab each list of URLs
        print('readpath = ' + readpath)

    if os.path.exists(readpath):
        file = open(readpath) # Open the list of URLs
        for lines in file: # Step through each URL in turn

            ruleString = '{"id":' + str(id) + ',"enabled":true, "category":"' + eachDirectory + '","description":"' + lines + '","flagged":true,"string":"' + lines + '","name":"","javaClass":"com.untangle.uvm.node.GenericRule","blocked":true}'
            #print(ruleString)
            finalJSON = finalJSON + ruleString # Create a rule and add it to the final string
            id = id + 1 # Increment the id after each rule
        file.close() # Close the file when all have been read

finalJSON = finalJSON + ']' # Close the JSON array

outputPath = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(path), 'Blacklist.json')
print('Output path = ' + outputPath)

outputFile = open(outputPath, 'w')
outputFile.write(finalJSON)
txtProgress.delete(0,END)
txtProgress.insert(0,"Process Complete")
outputFile.close()


def do_search():

    WriteThread = threading.Thread(target=update_the_status())
    CalcThread = threading.Thread(target=do_the_search())
    WriteThread.start()
    CalcThread.start()

def do_quit():
    print 'do_quit called'
    sys.exit()

#####################################
#       Build the interface         #
#####################################

#  Some global variables
path = ''

#  Create the application window and give it a title.
main  = Tk()
main.geometry('600x400')
main.title('Blacklist JSON array builder')

#  Populate the window with widgets.
lbSpace1 = Label(main, text='')
lbSpace1.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3)

lbDesc = Message(main, width=800, text='After you have unzipped the .tar file select the blacklist folder \nthat has been created using the browse button. Then click start.  The Blacklist.json \nfile will be created in the same directory as the Blacklist folder.')
lbDesc.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=4, pady=10)

lbPath = Label(main, text='Directory')
lbPath.grid(row=2, column=0, pady=10)

txtPath = Entry(main, width=50)
txtPath.grid(row=2, column=1)

pbPath = Button(main, text='Browse', command=loadpath)
pbPath.grid(row=2, column=2)

lbSpace2 = Label(main, text='')
lbSpace2.grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=3)

pbStart = Button(main, text='Begin', command=do_search)
pbStart.grid(row=4, column=1, sticky=W, pady=20)

pbQuit = Button(main, text='Quit', command=do_quit)
pbQuit.grid(row=4, column=2, sticky=W)

lbSpace3 = Label(main, text='')
lbSpace3.grid(row=5, column=0, columnspan=3)

txtProgress = Entry(main, width=50)
txtProgress.grid(row=6, column=1)
txtProgress.insert(0,'Waiting')


mainloop()
```

Thanks for the help guys.